# Application of Rouche's theorem gives two different answers?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

So I am supposed to find how many solutions the equation $z^7-5z^4+iz^2-2 = 0$ has in the region $|z|<1$. Here's the dilemma:

$|z^7-5z^4+iz^2|= |(-1)(-z^7+5z^4-iz^2)| = |-z^7+5z^4-iz^2| \geq -|z|^7+|5z^4-iz^2|\geq -|z|^7+5|z|^4-|z|^2 = -1+5-1 = 3 > 2$ (using the triangle inequality) on the circle $|z|=1$, which tells us that $f(z)$ has 7 solutions within the region.

However,

$|z^7+iz^2-2|\leq|z|^4+|iz|^2+|-2| \leq 1+1+2 = 4 \leq 5 = |-5z^4|$, which leads me to believe that there are 4 solutions within the region.

I am really confused! I am probably making a really silly mistake. Can someone please help me out? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wah, my bad. This was me being stupid. They both have 4 solutions (including multiplicity) in the region. Now it makes sense. I forgot initially to consider the fact that I am solely supposed to consider the solutions within the region $|z| <1$.

Using Wolfram Alpha, I discovered that in the region $|z|<1$ the factorization for $z^7−5z^4+iz^2 = 0$ gives us 3 solutions, two of multiplicity one, and one of multiplicity two. Meanwhile, in the same region, $−5z^4=0$ gives us one solution of multiplicity 4. Thus, we have including multiplicity, 4 solutions in the region for the equation $z^7−5z^4+iz^2−2=0$. Note that Rouche's theorem applied here does **not** give us the number of  **distinct** factors $z-a$ with $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|<1$ but instead tells us $z^7−5z^4+iz^2−2= p(x)q(x)$ where $p(x)$ is of degree 3 and has all its roots in $|z|>1$ and $q(z)$ is of degree 4 and has all its roots in $|z|<1$.
(That is what it means to have 4 solutions including multiplicity.)

I would like to thank leshik for his help!

Answer (score 4):

Well, the first method does not imply that the equation has $7$ solutions. More precisely, by Rouches theorem it has the same number of solutions as an upper dominant, which is $z^7-5z^4+iz^2.$ There nothing wrong with your second method, except that the last inequality has to be made strict and I would suggest to use in this particular case.

Comment: Ahh! That makes a lot more sense! I computed the solutions to $z^7+iz^2−2=0$ and found only one solution in the region described. For some reason, my prof's solutions say that we have 4 solutions in the region, which is incorrect, I guess, since $-5z^4=0$ has only one solution. Would that be right?

Comment: Rouches theorem counts the number of roots with their multiplicities. In other words, $-5z^4$ has four roots, all of them are zeros though.

Comment: But in that case $z^7+iz^2−2=0$ has only one root which is $z=0$ with multiplicity 2?